# Snytax error when inserting serialized value?

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

My code:

```
 $meta_ar = array("event_id" =>  $event_id, "user_id" => $user_id, "dbe" => $dbe, "hbe" => $hbe, "forum_id" => 'dummy_forum');

        $meta_ar = serialize($meta_ar);

        $db->query_write("
            INSERT INTO " . TABLE_PREFIX . "event_mod 
                (event_meta)
            VALUES
                (" . $meta_ar . ")
        ");
```

The error:

```
Invalid SQL:

            INSERT INTO event_mod 
                (event_meta)
            VALUES


    (a:5:{s:8:"event_id";N;s:7:"user_id";s:1:"1";s:3:"dbe";i:45;s:3:"hbe";i:32;s:8:"forum_id";s:11:"dummy_forum";});

MySQL Error   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':5:{s:8:"event_id";N;s:7:"user_id";s:1:"1";s:3:"dbe";i:45;s:3:"hbe";i:32;s:8:"fo' at line 4
Error Number  : 1064
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to so that the value enclosed in single quote.

When you pass any string to any column which is supposed to hold string value then that must be enclosed in the quotes.

```
 $db->query_write("
            INSERT INTO " . TABLE_PREFIX . "event_mod 
                (event_meta)
            VALUES
                ('" . $meta_ar . "')
        ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [PreparedStatement](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php), your Serialized Array is not escaped.